# Is there a way to use GSAP to swipe through swiper js thumb gallery?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js, gsap

I tried using gsap pin section feature and ScrollTrigger to go next slide.

```
<div style="--swiper-navigation-color: #fff; --swiper-pagination-color: #fff" class="swiper mySwiper2">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
      </div>
....
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  </div>
  <div thumbsSlider="" class="swiper mySwiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
      </div>
....
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
      spaceBetween: 10,
      slidesPerView: 4,
      freeMode: true,
      watchSlidesProgress: true,
    });
    var swiper2 = new Swiper(".mySwiper2", {
      spaceBetween: 10,
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
      },
      thumbs: {
        swiper: swiper,
      },
    });
  const swiper = gsap.to('.mySwiper2', {
    yPercent: -100 * (document.querySelectorAll('.mySwiper2.swiper-slide').length - 1),
    ease: 'none',
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: '.swiper-container',
      pin: true,
      scrub: 0.5,
      end: '+=100%',
      markers: true // Optional: Add markers for visualization
    }
  });
  </script>
```

I tired going though both documentation and gsap not working. I want to be able pin the swiper section till the last slide. than continue normal scroll.